# При запуске javafx программы выдает ошибку

Tags: java, файлы, javafx, видео

Пытаюсь написать программу, которая будет проигрывать видео во весь экран. При запуске выдает ошибку.
Основной код программы:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("1.mp4");
    Media media = new Media(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);

    DoubleProperty width = mediaView.fitWidthProperty();
    DoubleProperty height = mediaView.fitHeightProperty();
    width.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mediaView.sceneProperty(), "width"));
    height.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mediaView.sceneProperty(), "height"));
    mediaView.setPreserveRatio(true);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(mediaView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500, Color.BLUE);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("ScreenSaver");
    stage.setFullScreen(true);
    stage.show();

    mediaPlayer.play();
}
```

}

При запуске выдает ошибку:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1081)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager (in unnamed module @0x1d7d8f4b) cannot access class com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.glass.utils to unnamed module @0x1d7d8f4b
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.lambda$new$0(NativeMediaManager.java:111)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.<init>(NativeMediaManager.java:108)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager$NativeMediaManagerInitializer.<clinit>(NativeMediaManager.java:78)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getDefaultInstance(NativeMediaManager.java:90)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.canPlayProtocol(MediaManager.java:78)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:240)
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:393)
    at main.start(main.java:24)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application main
```

Смена версии языка ломает программу.

Comment: Что значит `Смена версии языка ломает программу`?  У вас не возникала эта ошибка на старых версиях Java?  Какая версия была рабочей?

Comment: См. [Module error when running JavaFx media application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237287/) -- аналогичная ошибка при запуске JavaFX приложения на Java 11.

Comment: Все работает. Я очень вам благодарен!!!